# Store selected image id in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to store the selected image in JQuery but I cannot get it to work.

I have created a JSFiddle of a simple abstraction of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uytb3/

Here is my html

```
<img id='test_img' src='https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
```

And here is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $("img").load(function()
    {
       var id = this.id;
       $("p").text('Image ID is' + id);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` is probably what you want.

Comment: Which is exactly the same as `this.id`, only slower. The problem lies more with `$(img)` instead of `$("img")` IMHO.

Comment: In passing, note that the `load` event is tricky to work with. It won't always be triggered, especially if the image is already stored in the browser's cache.

Comment: Too many caveats to using .load() with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that answered. The problem was img was not in quotes and I used the wrong method.

This solved my problem for anyone else looking:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("img").click(function(){
      var id = this.id;
        $("p").text('Image ID:' + id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To select `img` tags you need quotes around the selector:

```
$("img").load(function()
{
   var id = this.id;
   $("p").text('Image ID is' + id);
});
```

Otherwise you are passing in a variable called `img` which probably doesn't exist. `document` works because `document` is a valid variable name.

Comment: @ChrisHardie since when?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `id` is valid on HTMLelement, I thought we were dealing with a jQuery object. Going to get more coffee now.